# Is it necessary to use Amazon SNS when using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) on AWS to send notifications?

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I have an existing mobile app that can receive push notifications and I have an existing backend application that exposes an API for sending notifications to the app. The backend application uses Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), so it could be considered a wrapper around FCM. My backend application uses the Firebase Admin SDK to create messages and send them to Firebase. My customers hit an API exposed by my backend application (so, if we assume that the customer is using Postman, then the flow for sending a message is: Postman->My backend application->Firebase->Mobile app).

Until now I have been running my backend application on a local server, and it works fine. But now I need to deploy this on AWS. My question is: is it necessary to use Amazon SNS or not? I don't really need any additional functionality from AWS, I just want AWS to permit the required communication.

For example, I dont need to go to an AWS interface to enter the token to send messages to my phone. I already have an API exposed through my backend for sending messages. So, should I even bother to set up SNS?

I know that at a minimum I will have to make my firebase project google credentials available to my instance on AWS (in a file located at the path specified using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS). What other configuration steps would be needed? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

After some investigation I found that it is not necessary to use Amazon SNS to achieve what I wanted to achieve.

I was able to deploy my server application (which uses Firebase Cloud Message) to AWS, and the messages arrive on the mobile phones without any problem.

I initialized my backend application using the steps described on the Google Firebase site: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: I had, literally, this exact question. Thank you for posting the question and answer. You helped.